# Running time for an algorithm that sums up integers

Tags: arrays, runtime, sum

I am having trouble on an assignment regarding running time.

The problem statement is: 
"Isabel has an interesting way of summing up the values in an array A of n integers, where n is a power of two. She creates an array B of half the size of A, and sets B[i] = A[2i] + A[2i+1], for i=0,1,…,(n/2)-1. If B has size 1, then she outputs B[0]. Otherwise, she replaces A with B, and repeats the process. What is the running time of her algorithm?"

Would this be considered a O(log n) or a O(n)? I am thinking O(log n) because you would keep on dividing the array in half until you get the final result and I believe the basis of O(log n) is that you do not traverse the entire data structure. However in order to compute the sum, you have to access each element within the array thus making me think that it could possibly be O(n). Any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As you figured out yourself, you do need to access all elements to compute the sum. So your proposition:

> I believe the basis of O(log n) is that you do not traverse the entire data structure

does not hold. You can safely disregard the possibility of the algorithm being `O(log n)` then.

As for being `O(n)` or something different, you need to think about how many operations will be done as a whole. [George Skoptsov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15078680/520779) gives a good hint at that. I'd just like to call attention to a fact (from my own experience) that to determine "the running time" you need to take everything into account: memory access, operations, input and output, etc. In your simple case, only looking at the accesses (or the number of sums) might be enough, but in practice you can have very skewed results if you don't look at the problem from every angle.

Comment: This is clearly homework... I think we should avoid giving explicit answers to these problems.

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov I agree, and I think your answer was better than mine. There has been a lot of discussion on meta about how to deal with homework questions, and I recall reading that they should be treated just like regular questions. But I might be mistaken (or the policy might have changed)

Comment: Heh, I don't follow meta... I disagree with this policy. I can understand helping someone to move forward with a problem, but not providing the solution to a person that was explicitly asked to derive it on his/her own.

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov That's right, what I meant is that we're not supposed to give special treatment for these question just because they're homework. If they are interesting, answer, otherwise vote to close (as too localized, probably). But you are correct that the intention should be in helping to learn, not spoon feeding a quick answer that can be copy/pasted without thinking. In any case, I changed my whole answer, as the previous one was really not good.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Thank you for the quick response, I really appreciate it. I thought both responses were great because they made me analyze the problem more comprehensively by using examples.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe the basis of O(log n) is that you do not traverse the entire
>   data structure.

There's no basis for beliefs or guesses. Run through the algorithm mentally. 
How many recursions are there going to be for array `A` of size `n`?
How many summations are there going to be for each recursion (when array A is of size `n`)?

- First run: `n/2` summations, `n` accesses to elements of `A`
- .
- .
- .
- Last run: `1` summation, `2` accesses to elements of `A`

How many runs are there total? When you sum this up, what is the highest power of `n`?